# Problem drawing a SVG from file using React and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to program a SVG manipulation app using React and I'm using JQuery to read and filter the svg file, but I don't know why when I use `.map()` doesn't works, but  when I draw a path accessing an element from the array of paths using something like `paths[0]` it works.

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'

class Tile extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        paths: [],
        fills: [],
        transforms: [],
        strokeWidths: [],
        foo: ["1234", "2345"]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    $.get("xml/svg.xml", (xml) => {
        $(xml).find('path').each((index, path) => {
            self.setState({ paths: [...self.state.paths, $(path).attr('d')] })
            self.setState({ fills: [...self.state.fills, $(path).attr('fill')] })
            const transform = ($(path).attr('transform') !== undefined) ? $(path).attr('transform') : "translate(0 0)"
            self.setState({
                transforms: [...self.state.transforms, transform]
            })
        });
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="tile">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                {this.state.paths.map((path, index) => {
                    <path d={path} transform={this.state.transforms[index]} fill={this.state.fills[index]} stroke={this.state.strokeWidths[index]}></path>
                })}
            </svg>
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d={this.state.paths[1]}></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Tile
```

SVG file:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0-0.099609v19a19 19 0 0 0 19-19zm185 0.099609v15h15v-15zm15.041 170a30 30 0 0 0-30 30h30zm-200.04 15v15h15v-15z" fill="#d40000"/>
    <path d="m128.81 97.034a30.508 28.39 0 0 1-30.508 28.39 30.508 28.39 0 0 1-30.508-28.39 30.508 28.39 0 0 1 30.508-28.39 30.508 28.39 0 0 1 30.508 28.39z" fill="#ff7fff" stroke-width="0"/>
</svg>
```

Any suggestion or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? My guess is on the initial render you're probably getting a few something-is-undefined errors. Also, in component did mount, I would not call setState inside the map function. That will cause the component to rerender for ever added path

Comment: I lost 1 day because I have a lot of "unimportant" warnings and among them I had something very important:
"./src/components/designApp/Tile.jsx Line 34: Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return Line 35: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions". I missed the return on the arrow function because I'm using {} and not (), I will never omit a warning no matter how insignificant it seems. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your callback for fetching the data to set state only once, and changed your render to only render if the `paths` exist. I also noticed your posted code does not parse `stroke-width`, so I added that in, as well as the missing return on your map, as you mentioned in your comment Also, I would recommend getting away from reliance on jQuery. Here's a good reference: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

class Tile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paths: [],
      fills: [],
      transforms: [],
      strokeWidths: [],
      foo: ["1234", "2345"]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    $.get("xml/svg.xml", xml => {

      const paths = [];
      const fills = [];
      const transforms = [];
      const strokeWidths = [];

      $(xml)
        .find("path")
        .each((index, path) => {
          const transform =
            path.getAttribute("transform") !== undefined
              ? path.getAttribute("transform")
              : "translate(0 0)";
          transforms.push(transform);
          paths.push(path.getAttribute("d"));
          fills.push(path.getAttribute("fill"));
          strokeWidths.push(path.getAttribute("stroke-width")); //?? not included in your original code
        });

      self.setState({ paths, fills, transforms, strokeWidths });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { paths, fills, transforms, strokeWidths } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="tile">
        {paths.length > 1 && [
          <svg
            key="svg1"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 200 200"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            {paths.map((path, index) => (
              <path
                d={path}
                transform={transforms[index]}
                fill={fills[index]}
                stroke={strokeWidths[index]}
              />;
            ))}
          </svg>,
          <svg
            key="svg2"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 200 200"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <path d={paths[1]} />
          </svg>
        ]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Tile;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!, I'm just starting with React and I'm studying the book "React Quickly" but I'm very raw with Javascript, can you suggest me a serious book about Javascript? Until a few days ago I had never used javascript and most books looks very basic for me and I don't want to "lose" time learning about loops because I already know C++,C# and Java but I'm always afraid of missing important information if I skip a chapter. Any suggestiongs? and again Thank you!!